# smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed and i can't fix it

Tags: python, sendmail

i use code:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from ...models import User as midas_user
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@receiver(post_save, sender=midas_user)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        logger.info("New user created: %s", instance.name)
        send_mail("midas_user.instance",
                  "Here is the message",
                  "miriamotuss@gmail.com",
                  ["ah2600381@gmail.com"]
                  )
```

my settings:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "miriamotuss@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'i change this string'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

if i try to create user i have error:

```
shop-backend-back         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 640, in auth
shop-backend-back         |     (code, resp) = self.docmd("AUTH", mechanism + " " + response)
shop-backend-back         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 430, in docmd
shop-backend-back         |     return self.getreply()
shop-backend-back         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 403, in getreply
shop-backend-back         |     raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
shop-backend-back         | smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

i just first time try yo use send_mail and take this. how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

To use Gmail like this, you will need to follow the instructions shown here:

https://support.google.com/mail/thread/40988320?hl=en

As written there:

> If you have two-step verification (2SV) enabled on the account, you
> will need to use an application specific password (created in the
> Gmail account) in the app settings: Signing in using
> application-specific passwords
>
> If 2SV is not enabled, you must enable access for less secure apps:
> sign into the Gmail account using a web browser at
> https://mail.google.com, then go to Settings > Accounts and Import >
> Other Google Account settings.  Under Security, scroll down and enable
> access for less secure apps. This setting is required to enable SMTP,
> POP or IMAP access.

This article also includes some further troubleshooting steps.

But it is clear from your error, this is not a python issue.